# How to use jQuery function stored as a value in an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

I am a little over my head with understanding why this is not working and how to fix it.

I have an object created using wp_localize_script() in another file and I'm using it to pass a value to my js file.

I am passing other more static values this same way and it is working well, but I have one instance where the value I am passing is a jQuery function that I need to be executed.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function ($) {

    if( wptjCustomInit.opt != "" ) {

        wptjCustomInit.opt;

        console.log(wptjCustomInit.opt); //outputs correct content: $('.table-juice').DataTable();

    }else{

    ...other code...
```

My goal is for the content of the object to be processed along with the rest of the script as if it had been in the file all along.

I'm guessing I just don't understand something fundamental and I'm not getting to the right scenario in my search attempts. I'm grateful for any help! (sorry for my ignorance)

Comment: Not quite sure I get it, wp_localize lets you send data from the PHP backend to the frontend. It does this by inserting a script with variables and the PHP content so it can be accessed on the clientside and it's quite neat, but how exactly do you send a jQuery object from PHP where there is no jQuery nor any javascript ?

Comment: I suspect `wptjCustomInit.opt` contains the string `$('.table-juice')....` and not really a jQuery object, and that would be the wrong way to do that, if it's the selector you need you should just pass that, not entire strings of jQuery ?

Comment: You might be on the right track. You are correct about the content of the string. 

wptjCustomInit is an array and "opt" is the only key/value in the array. I'm probably wrong calling it an object from the jQuery perspective, but that's what they called it in the docs for wp_localize_script().

Comment: `wptjCustomInit` is an object, and `opt` is a property that you've attached to that object, you've made this by creating a data structure in PHP on the serverside in Wordpress that sets a value to `opt` and that value is probably the string `$('.table-juice').DataTable()` which means nothing to PHP, and when inserting it into javascript it means nothing there as well, it's just a string. You could eval the string, but that's not the right way to do it, you shouldn't be passing entire strings containing javascript, you pass variables you need from the server so you can use them on the clientsid

Comment: Thanks for that explanation!!! That really helped me understand the lingo much better. You are correct about my string content and my question is essentially how to make that string meaningful to jQuery? I also understand that this could be something dangerous. It has a unique purpose in the admin settings for a plugin. I want to allow advanced users an ability to override my init function and use their own. The primary purpose of the plugin is to integrate the DataTables library and while I have a limited set of options, advanced users might want to override mine and add their own.

Comment: I tested your suggestion that I could do eval() on the string and that works! Sometimes I just don't know what to search for. You did raise a bigger question of doing this right and as safely as possible for the user. Given my longer explanation above, do you have any advice in that area? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You'd probably be better of just echoing the string into a script tag, there are ways to do that in wordpress, instead of using wp_localize, which isn't meant for javascript strings but rather simple primitive values you want to transfer from the server to the javascript

Comment: Or if it's just an object of options passed to dataTables, you could pass that as JSON to wp_localize and insert it into the dataTables function call, you just can't pass the entire jQuery string as it won't be executed

Comment: OK, I'll explore your suggestion to echo the string. My initial feeling was that I can control the output of my js file better, but I'm sure I can do the same within the php. I am adding certain options, but my goal for this specific function was to give the user a textarea and a switch to use/not use the content to replace my entire init string. Thanks again! Do you want to create an answer, since you did answer my original question?

Comment: Try it out and see if you can come up with something that actually works, then write up an answer yourself that you can accept with the actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, it might be as simple as just adding parentheses to the method name:

```
wptjCustomInit.opt();
```

That is the standard way to call a method.

Comment: I just tested this and I get this error in the console:

Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function

Comment: I think I am learning from other comments that I don't really have a js object, but a string. Do I need to create a function that executes the string?

Answer (score 0):

Even though I am answering my own question, it comes with the help of those who commented on this question.

The solution is to use the javascript eval() function. Like this:

```
eval(wptjCustomInit.opt);
```

From [W3Schools about eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp):

> The eval() function evaluates or executes an argument.
>
> If the argument is an expression, eval() evaluates the expression. If
>   the argument is one or more JavaScript statements, eval() executes the
>   statements.

I greatly appreciate the help and time spent helping me understand and solve the problem!